# supports-screens and image still the same

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm using android 2.3.3. 
I've created two devices: normal screen `HVGA` and large screen with `WVGA854`. 
I've added images to `drawable-mdpi` with size 58x58px and another images to `drawable-hdpi` with size 144x144px.
I've also added some text to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" 
    android:anyDensity="true">
</supports-screens>
```

I assume, two of them (devices) will show me two different sizes of images. But somehow both show the same images from `mdpi`.
I know it because images in hdpi should be rotated clockwise.

I've read this links but I'm still confused. Help.

**Links:**

[Tutorial: Multiple Screen Support](http://web.archive.org/web/20100916182949/http://wonton-games.blogspot.com/2010/07/tutorial-multiple-screen-support.html)
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Am I right if I say that this app will be available only for normal and larger sreen devices?

Comment: How large was the screen you created for your second emulator?  MDPI, HDPI, etc. is based on pixel density.  If your second screen was large enough, then density would be the same or lower than your HVGA emulator.

Comment: I've used default settings for emulator. I've not changed any density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the "Abstracted LCD Density" Hardware property in the emulator settings. It goes from 120dpi (ldpi) to 312dpi (xhdpi).